# What is this probability of a random power of 2 beginning with 1?

Tags: probability

What is this the probability that a random  positive integer power of 2 begins with 1?BY a random power  I mean a natural number chosen randomly from the set of natural numbers.

Comment: How are the integers 'randomly' chosen? With what distribution? I suspect you really want some kind of asymptotic answer.

Comment: This question is not meaningful until you specify the probability distribution on the set of powers of 2 under which you want to compute the probability.

Comment: The power of 2 is chosen uniformly and randomly from the set {1,2,3,.....,n}.I want the limiting probability as n goes to infinity

Comment: There are infinite integers !!!.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417486/probability-that-the-first-digit-of-2n-is-1

Answer (score 1):

[30.102999566398119521373889472449302676819%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law#Distributions_known_to_obey_Benford.27s_Law)

Answer (score 1):

We want to know when we have $10^n \leq 2^k < 2\cdot 10^n$. Taking $\log$, this becomes $n \leq k \log_{10}(2) < \log_{10}(2) + n$. Modulo $\mathbb{Z}$, our question is now about asymptotics of how often $k\log_{10}(2) \pmod{\mathbb{Z}}$ lands in the interval $[0,\log_{10}(2)] \subseteq [0,1]$. Since $\log_{10}(2)$ is irrational, I believe that the distribution is basically uniform, and so the probability should simply be $\log_{10}(2) \approx 0.301$.