# Riddle : Given an integer power, does any integer to this power start with the power?

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I initially found the following riddle somewhere : Is there an integer $n$ such that $n^{2004}$ starts (from the left) by $2004$ ?

I was unable to find an answer, but I found the question rather interesting and couldn't find any such question on MSE, hence I'm wondering :

**Given a non trivial positive integer $a$, when is there a positive integer $n$ such that $n^a$ starts by $a$ ?**

(By trivial integers I mean cases like $a=1,a=2,\dots$ etc for which $n$ can very easily be found)

Comment: Indeed, you can always take $n=2$.  Adapt the proof shown, e.g., here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417486/probability-that-the-first-digit-of-2n-is-1

Comment: In other words, given $a$, you want to find $n$ such that $$a\cdot10^k \leq n^a < ( a + 1 )\cdot 10^k$$ for some $k$. It seems to me that, taking $k$ really large, one should expect to find *some* $a$-th power in the corresponding range.

Comment: @Blue.  Indeed you can, so long as $n$ is not a power of $10$ anyway.  Look at the map which takes a positive number $x$ to the fractional part of $log_{10}(x)$.  That's a map to the circle and multiplication by $n$ becomes addition with $log_{10}(n)$.  Unless $n$ is a power of $10$ this is the same as a rotation by an irrational angle, hence iterating this map gives a dense subset of the circle.

Comment: Is it even computable without keeping all digits in memory?

Comment: $4017382^{2004}$ begins with $2004$. That number has 13,235 digits.

Comment: @columbus8myhw Can you share your algorithm (pastebin,...) ? Thanks :-)

Comment: I just messed around with Wolfram Alpha. Solving for $m_k$ in Wofsey's answer, I found out that it had to be at least $4017018$. So I tried $4017500$, which turned out to be too large. Then I tried $4017300$, which was too small. Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is always possible.  As stated in the comments, you are looking for an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a\cdot 10^k\leq n^a<(a+1)\cdot 10^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.  For any $k$, let $m_k$ be the largest integer such that $m_k^a< a\cdot 10^k$.  Then $(m_k+1)^a\geq a\cdot 10^k$, and $(m_k+1)^a<(a+1)\cdot 10^k$ as long as $$\left(\frac{m_k+1}{m_k}\right)^a\leq\frac{a+1}{a}.$$  This last inequality is true as long as $m_k$ is sufficiently large, since the left-hand side converges to $1$ as $m_k\to \infty$.  But $m_k\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$, so this inequality must hold for all sufficiently large $k$.  Thus $n=m_k+1$ is a number of the sort you seek for all sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks :D

Comment: Using your answer and Wolfram Alpha, we get:$$4017382^{2004}\text{ begins with }2004$$

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of the following theorem (Lemma 2.1 in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.34.1370) on disjunctive sequences), whose proof is along the same lines as that posted in the answer by @EricWofsey:

> If $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$ is a strictly increasing infinite sequence
>   of positive integers such that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}
> \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$$ then for any positive integer $m$ and any
>   integer base $b \ge 2$, there is an $a_n$ whose expression in base $b$
>   starts with the expression of $m$ in base $b$.

Your result is then the very special case of taking $a_n = n^k$ and $k=m$. For this and some other special cases, see these [examples of disjunctive sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence#Examples). (E.g., for any desired positive integer, there are infinitely many prime numbers whose representation begins with the digits of that number.)

**NB**: For *any* positive integer exponent $k$ and *any* desired positive integer $m$, there are *infinitely many* positive integers $n$ such that the representation of $n^k$ starts with the representation of $m$; furthermore, this holds for digital representations in any integer base $b \ge 2$.